# Problem with side panel buttons Thinkpad L412, ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, kernel, thinkpad, volume-control

I have the following problem:
After a kernel update, my side panel buttons on my L412 to incresa/decrease and mute volume (also de mic mute) stopped working. I don't know how to fix this, and the solutions for the thinkpad T520 doesn't work.
Could someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!
The solution was to shutdown, unplug it and remove the battery. Wait for 1 minute, replace and it's fixed!

It seems to be the way that solves this problem in other Thinkpad models too.